# How to push out a rise up menu over his area with css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I put in the bottom area of my site a table with filtering and sorting
[dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRVeH.png).

But I don't like as it's now, so I've converted it to a Rise Up menu, but unfortunately it seems don't work properly ([this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXPaT.png) is the result).

How can I show all the menu? I don't want to scroll up to show it all, I need to show it over all site content.